# Does the original iPad meet the minimum system requirements for NOVA 3?

Tags: ios, performance, nova-3

After some research, it would seem that nobody who owns an *original* iPad (1st generation) plays N.O.V.A. 3.

I'm asking if singleplayer and multiplayer are playable on the first iPad. In this case that means the fog isn't so close you can't see others, and the frame-rate isn't so low it's hard to control.

How is the performance of N.O.V.A. 3 on the original iPad?

Also, the multiplayer performance on the iPod 4 is supposed to be bad, so I was wondering if someone is able to confirm this too.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain down-vote

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, but I guess is because your question is very subjective. I believe your question is "How is the performance of NOVA3 on the original iPad" and this is not a good question. Could you make your question more **Game-specific hardware and utilities** so it fits more the site?

Comment: So are we talking about iPod 4 or iPad 1? How do you define 'good/bad performance' or any shade of grey that comes in between? You need to give us *your* benchmarks, before anyone can give you an objective measurement based on them.

Comment: @JamesJiao is it really that unclear? the last sentence is "How is the performance of N.O.V.A. 3 on the original iPad?"

Answer (score 2):

- Compatible devices: iPhone 3Gs, 4, 4S; iPod Touch (3rd and 4th generation), **iPad (all generations)**
- Supported resolutions: 480x320, 960x640, 1024x768, 2048x1536
- System Requirements: iOS 4.0 and above

Taken from [here](http://www.gfxtra.com/mobile-ios-games/195891-nova-3-near-orbit-vanguard-alliance-v100-action-ios-40engrus.html).

I believe that if you are able to reduce your resolution, you would be able to play NOVA 3 at a better performance level however sacrificing the quality of the graphics.